# Approval Process in salesforce

Tags: approval-process

Please find the details below:

I have 8 Approvers in My Approval process. and 3 Approvers are mandatory.
they are

1)Product Manager

2)Legal Manager

3)Regional Sales Manager

But my requirement is other 5 approvers are not mandatory. but if any of the 8 approvers approve the request it should move to the next step.

please find the screenshot of my Record:
[image] 
can someone please help me with this.
help will be really appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario 1)** Is it any one among those 8 approver should approve? 
OR
**Scenario 2)** Is it the first three Product, Legal & Regional are mandatory approvers should approve and then any one among the 5 should approve?

For scenario #1 - You can create an Unanimous Approval Process for all 8 managers
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321144&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1
[image]

For Scenario #2 - Create 3 steps of Approval for the first 3 Approvers - Legal, Product & Regional Approvals and then 4th step for the remaining 5 Users as Unanimous Approval Process.

Comment: Thanks, Praveen --> it is like among the 8 Approvers if any approver approves the request it should be approved.